# Can't override the order by method in Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel, sql-order-by, laravel-backpack

This is my setup function

```
$this->crud->setModel('App\Models\OrderDetail');
    $this->crud->setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/orderdetail');
    $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('product', 'products');
    setPermissions('order-detail', $this->crud);

    if(backpack_user()->hasRole('Merchant')){
        $this->crud->addClause('join','orders', function($query){
            $query->on('order_details.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
                ->where('user_id', backpack_user()->id);
        });
    }
    $this->crud->denyAccess(['create', 'update', 'show']);

    $this->crud->orderBy('order_details.id','DESC');
```

SQL error on Console

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `order_details` inner join `orders` on `order_details`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` and `user_id` = 4 where `status` = on-delivery order by `order_details`.`id` desc, `id` desc limit 10)
```

There is no order by clause running on Global Scope of the model

Comment: I didn't see where this part came from: `where \`status\` = on-delivery`. Are there any query modifications outside the code piece in question?

Comment: Yes i added a filer, but it doesn't work with or without filter

Comment: I think problem is in your join.

Comment: Yes I've had this problem aswell. I get the same error message. Laravel Backpack isn't using the default table name, instead using plain id for the second order statement.

Comment: yes backpack should use orderBy clause by adding its table names in front of the ordered column instead of using plain name